# Jmeter cannot record CDN js files

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, frontend, load

I got a requirement to record scripts to test the website load performance, and when I record the scripts, I found some of the files like js files are blocked.

While I was checking the website these files loading, I found these js files are 200 as they load.

I don't know why these files cannot be loaded when I use Jmeter and change the proxy of the browser.

I tried chrome and firefox, there is one file difference between the two browsers(the js file could be loaded in chrome when I do recording in Jmeter, while it cannot be loaded in firefox), and I had already install the certificate of Jmeter into these two browsers.

I hope someone encounter the same problem could answer this, how do you solve this issue? this CDN js files could not be loaded issue.

I can guess maybe something wrong with the website certificate...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to record the .js files (as well as images, fonts, styles, sounds, etc.) because:

1. They're **external** and not directly related to the domain you're testing. Your test should solely focus on your application domain and all resources which are coming from 3rd-party servers should be out of scope for your test
2. If you're using [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) you can see that .js (and others) are being excluded from the recording scope under "Requests Filtering" tab:

   [image]
3. Real browsers do download these images, scripts, styles, etc. but they do it in **parallel** and if you record these resources JMeter will replay them sequentially so it's better to tick these 2 boxes in the [HTTP Requests Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) in order to get browser-like behaviour:

   [image]

Comment: 1. Why don't we need CDN js files? Since they are needed when you browse the website normally.

Comment: 2. I use test script recorder as well, but why we need to exclude the js/css/woff assets when doing load testing?

Comment: 3. I use third party components to hold these recorded scripts which is parallel controller, it is similar to HTTP Request Defaults.